# How to play two voices with a very wide span

Tags: piano, technique, sheet-music

From image 1, the left hand of 2nd or 3rd measure has two voices if my understanding is correct.  But when I watched the author playing, she played just as in image 2 which has only one voice.

Any comments?

[image: Sustained low notes with higher triplets]
[image: As played, the hand does not sustain the low notes]

Comment: Did the author play with (unmarked) pedal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arranger almost certainly added some sustain pedal to maintain the sound of the low G and F. This is a standard piano technique, using the pedal to sustain one voice while moving the hand to play a second voice. Because it's so common, there is often no pedal marking — it's assumed. It's also understood that, since the pedal can only be added lightly and may even need to be changed during the passage, that the sustained note might fade before its written time.

The same technique is also discussed in [My hand is too small to play a section of the piece](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/104494/70803).